# Hover effect with html5, no javascript or css

Tags: html, hover, effects

I am trying to do a hover->highlight effect on the cells of the table in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/424WK/), so they will appear to look like buttons.  I can't use any javascript or CSS, but I can use HTML5.  Does anyone know how to do it.  I know there is an `onmouseover` attribute in HTML5, just not much experience yet.

Thanks!

Comment: That’s not possible. Why can’t you use CSS though?

Comment: `onmouseover` is JavaScript. And why can't you use CSS?

Comment: The reason i can't use JS or CSS is that I am trying to make custom content for a website which i am trying to build on sites.google.com.  They do not allow you to add JS or CSS to the page.

Comment: They do, you just have to click 'Edit HTML' or something similar, then add `style="<style here>"` to the element.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Even then you cannot change pseudoclasses though – which you’d need to change the hover effect.

Comment: I just realized that - you can still insert a `<style>` element though.

Comment: google sites does not allow inserting <style> elements anymore

Comment: Have you tried using the JavaScript `onmouseover` like this: [jsfiddle.net/JWhkn/](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhkn/)?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff - that looks good, but it looks like google sites blocks that too.

Comment: I don't have a Google site (I use [000Webhost](http://000webhost.com) and hand code my site), so I can't test if `onmouseover` works. Have you tried `onmouseover` yourself?

Comment: I mean, i see it work on jsfiddle, I usually use jQuery for all hover effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you want to change the appearance of a given element based on user's behavior you have to use JavaScript (event based) or the CSS pseudo class `:hover`.

However, if you can edit the HTML of your content, then you should be able to insert a custom `<style>` element or add event listeners. Note that the first isn't valid in HTML4*, in HTML5 you can use the `scoped` attribute to style [only a given scope](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-style-element.html#the-style-element) (but I don't think this behavior is implemented in any browser yet).

*This solution should work, even if the resulting code HTML4 isn't valid any more.